# Mapbox is not working giving error so tell me how its work giving following error

Tags: nativescript, mapbox

I am adding this code in my file it is not working and giving error 'mapboxsdk' undefined and nativescript-mapbox is not added on preview app also give me this as warning in yellow color. So now can I work with mapbox plugin I added my token too but it is not working.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'mapboxsdk' of undefined

HTML:

```
<ContentView height="100%" width="100%">
    <Mapbox
        accessToken="your_token"
        mapStyle="traffic_day"
        latitude="50.467735"
        longitude="13.427718"
        hideCompass="true"
        zoomLevel="18"
        showUserLocation="false"
        disableZoom="false"
        disableRotation="false"
        disableScroll="false"
        disableTilt="false"
        (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
    </Mapbox>
  </ContentView>
```

component.ts:

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement("Mapbox", () => require("nativescript-mapbox").MapboxView);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a missing plugin in NativeScript preview app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724758/how-to-handle-a-missing-plugin-in-nativescript-preview-app)

Comment: Applicable for any plugin with native dependency, that includes nativescript-mapbox. Use `tns [run|build]` instead of preview.

Comment: @Manoj  i am not run this application in emulator i want to run in my device

Comment: i have warning like this: Plugin nativescript-mapbox is not included in preview app on <device Id here> and will not work.

Comment: As Manoj explained - you cannot use this plugin with `tns preview`. Use `tns run` which works with real devices as well.

Comment: @anthares bt i have no emulator devices in my pc so this command can't work

Comment: No emulators are needed to use `tns run`. Just connect your real device to your PC.

Comment: any one have solution about this issue??